# Move element when UITextView expands

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, constraints

I am trying to make a TextView in my scrollview look like the "**Hoshi**" TextField in this github repo [raulriera TextFieldEffects](https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects)

If I only have a textview with top/left/right constraint it will expand when I enter more text which is right.

But when I add a UIView under it, it will cut off the text if I enter alot of characters, what I want to do is to move the view/line under it along with the textview when it expands.

My constrains for the UIView is **top space to textview >= 10** I thought that would move the View when the textview expands but nothing happens, instead the text gets cut off and the view wont move

Here is a image for the constraint:

[image]

So how can I make the view move once the textview expands?

Comment: What are the other constraints?

Comment: @matt The textView has a top/right/left constraint, all set to 10. I solved it by making the bottom constraint of the view have a low priority (250) - The big bottom one that you can see in the image. That allowed the view to hug the textView but also make it expand together with the textview

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically change the height constraint of the textview based on the text entered.

Comment: Is that possible to do when you enter text? I wont load in text, it will only work as a input. But can you change the height each time you do a new "<br> ?

Comment: You will get callback in the textview delegate methods when the text is entering by the user. Check the size of the text and adjust the height constraint IBOutlet accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `bottom constraints` of the `lable` it will work as desired.That `bottom constraints` don't allow your `lable` to move down as your `textView` height increases.

Comment: Yeah, but how will the line/view then be able to follow the textview once it expands?

Comment: As line/ view height is fix & its top is given to textView ,there is no need of bottom constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I had to set the UIView's bottom constraint to be >= low priority (250). That would make it expand together with the textview